# Signup form error checking

Tags: php, validation, user-registration

I have a class that contains two functions, one called signup() and one called p_signup(). p_signup() is where my form is processed that is sent to the view in signup.

I have error checking in p_signup with an errors array -- how do I make this errors array available to the the view that I send things to in signup?

Btw, when there are more than 0 errors, I reroute the user to signup/error, which is where I would like to be sending my errors

Can I share a variable in between the two functions somehow by referencing the other?

maybe like: `this->p_signup->errors_array`?

Comment: Post the code please?

Answer (score 1):

You can store error messages in session and call display method in a view file which will display error messages from session and destruct message. Many mvc frameworks are call this mechanism as "flash messages".

Comment: Yep, what fr05t1k said is correct. I recommend looking at CakePHP and CodeIgniter to see how they handle flash messaging to display error/confirmation messages between page requests.

Comment: @AgmLauncher actually CodeIgniter and CakePHP are **two worst** frameworks in PHP.